# US contact person details in DS 160 form

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, applications

I do not have any relatives in US of whom i can mention in my application. What should I mention in this ask as i am unable to tick i do not know for Known person or known organisation in the US contact section of the DS 160 form

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.